# Postgresql string to jsonb_each_text()

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I have this string (character varying) as a row value in Postgresql :

```
{'img_0': 'https://random.com/xxxxxx.jpg', 'img_1': 'https://random.com/yyyyyy.jpg', 'img_2': 'https://random.com/zzzzzz.jpg'}
```

I am trying to json_eact_text() it but can't figure out how to.
I have tried to_jsonb() on it (working) and then jsonb_each(), but I have this error :

```
ERROR:  cannot call jsonb_each on a non-object
```

My query :

```
WITH 
test AS (
    SELECT to_jsonb(value) as value FROM attribute_value WHERE id = 43918
)

SELECT jsonb_each(value) FROM test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your text value is not valid JSON.  JSON requires doublequotes (`"`) to delimit strings.

This will work by doctoring your text provided that your data is consistently wrong:

```
with t (sometext) as (
  values ($${'img_0': 'https://random.com/xxxxxx.jpg', 'img_1': 'https://random.com/yyyyyy.jpg', 'img_2': 'https://random.com/zzzzzz.jpg'}$$)
)
select jsonb_each_text(replace(sometext, '''', '"')::jsonb)
  from t;

            jsonb_each_text            
---------------------------------------
 (img_0,https://random.com/xxxxxx.jpg)
 (img_1,https://random.com/yyyyyy.jpg)
 (img_2,https://random.com/zzzzzz.jpg)
(3 rows)
```

To break this out into columns:

```
with t (sometext) as (
  values ($${'img_0': 'https://random.com/xxxxxx.jpg', 'img_1': 'https://random.com/yyyyyy.jpg', 'img_2': 'https://random.com/zzzzzz.jpg'}$$)
)
select j.*
  from t
 cross join lateral jsonb_each_text(replace(sometext, '''', '"')::jsonb) as j;

  key  |             value             
-------+-------------------------------
 img_0 | https://random.com/xxxxxx.jpg
 img_1 | https://random.com/yyyyyy.jpg
 img_2 | https://random.com/zzzzzz.jpg
(3 rows)
```

Comment: I had the replace() wrong. Is it possible to have 'img_0' and 'https://random.com/xxxxxx.jpg' in two different columns ?

Comment: @IndiaSke  Certainly.  Please see the update to the answer.